# How to disable root password in NixOS?

Tags: password, root, nixos, nix

I tried setting `users.users.root.hashedPassword = "*";` similar to `sudo passwd -d root` or

```
user { 'root':
  password => '*',
  require  => Package[ruby-shadow],
}
```

in [Puppet](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/blob/e8bb1b3b3bfd8e6fd2cfa973045939ac69730c9f/modules/users/manifests/init.pp), but after `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` I'm still able to `su -` with the old password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `mutableUsers` to `false` and the **user password**.

```
users = {

 #normal users declaration here

  mutableUsers = false;

  extraUsers = {

    root = {
      hashedPassword = "*";
    };
     user = {
      hashedPassword = "user-password";
    }; 
   };
};
```

The manpage : `man configuration.nix`

```
   users.users.<name?>.hashedPassword
       Specifies the hashed password for the user. The options
       hashedPassword, password and passwordFile controls what password is
       set for the user.  hashedPassword overrides both password and
       passwordFile.  password overrides passwordFile. If none of these
       three options are set, no password is assigned to the user, and the
       user will not be able to do password logins. If the option
       users.mutableUsers is true, the password defined in one of the
       three options will only be set when the user is created for the
       first time. After that, you are free to change the password with
       the ordinary user management commands. If users.mutableUsers is
       false, you cannot change user passwords, they will always be set
       according to the password options.
```

You can set a label to test the new generation (labled `noroot`):

```
nixos-rebuild switch -p noroot -I nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix
```

Comment: Hold on, does `mutableUsers = false` mean I'd have to hardcode *everybody's* passwords (hashed or not) in my configuration? If so this is not an option.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Is it possible to configure *only* the root user's password and still have other users with a custom password?